# How to use web view inside a list view in xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, webview

I want to display a web view in list view using MVVM data binding on HTML source

Comment: Place a WebView control inside of the ListView template.  Have you tried this?  There is nothing particularly complex about it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try this code:
for your xaml file:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <local:HtmlSourceConverter x:Key="HtmlSourceConverter" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<ListView>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ViewCell>
            <WebView Source="{Binding MyHtml, Converter={StaticResource HtmlSourceConverter}}" />
         </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Value converter:

```
public class HtmlSourceConverter : IValueConverter {
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
      var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();

      if (value != null){
         html.Html = value.ToString();
      }
   
      return html;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture){
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Model

```
public class MyWebSite
{
   public string MyHtml { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
private IList<MyWebSite> _list;
public IList<MyWebSite> List
{
   get{
      return _list;
   }
   set{
      _list = value;
   }
}
...
public MainPageModel()
{
   List = new List<MyWebSite>(){
      new MyWebSite(){
         MyHtml = "<html><body><h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1><p>Welcome to WebView 1</p></body></html>"
      },
      ...
      ...

   }
}
```